# Definir variável para template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Preciso definir uma variável que será exibida no rodapé de todas as minhas páginas, ou seja, no template do cake 3. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Por favor, leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Na documentação da ferramenta tem como passar variáveis do *controller* para a *view*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não é necessário exemplo de código, tudo o que preciso é a informação de onde inserir uma variável que será passada para a view de layout.

Comment: Já tentou ver algo na [documentação](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#view-events)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que ver a situação, tem várias formas de fazer isso, uma delas é passando no beforeRender ou no initialize do AppController, e setar a variável lá, de forma que todas as views do sistema tenham acesso.

Comment: Sim, atualmente estou fazendo pelo beforeRender do AppController, mas ainda acho que deve ter alguma forma melhor e mais específica. Estou passando variáveis desnecessárias para as views que não usam esse layout.